# Wordpress - How do I can change file in theme is used when page is loaded by browser?

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, when I set active for any theme and index.php file in this will be called. Today, I've installed one theme and it requires install some plugins. I installed them and then I refresh. My home page used page.php file in theme to execute instead of using index.php file as normal. How do I change default execute file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default WordPress template file is index.php for all templates but if you select "Static Page" for your home page than the default template file will be page.php and not index.php

You can read in detail about the difference between the 2 files and how to manage them here on [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)